# Building submodule binary crates with cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following crate structure:

```
|── proj/
    └── src/
        └── bin/
            └── foo-bin-rs/
                └── src/
                    └── main.rs
                └── Cargo.toml
        └── main.rs
    └── Cargo.toml
    └── build.rs
```

`foo-bin-rs` is a submodule. I'd like to find a clean way to issue a build
command through cargo that would build `foo-bin-rs` as a part of the build
command used for `proj`. I've not found any documentation that uses the
`src/bin` directory with binaries that are their own separate crate, just
single files. My first thought was to have a `build.rs` that issued its own
`cargo` command, but I couldn't find a flag for cargo that allowed passing a
directory to use as root. What is the canonical solution for this?

Comment: I do not understand very well what you ask, my English is not good, but maybe this will help you, added in your initial **Cargo.toml** `[dependencies.foo]
path = "./proj/src/bin"`

Comment: @AngelAngel Thanks for the suggestion, but `foo` isn't a dependency needed to compile like a lib, but a separate rust program with it's own compilation steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first thought was to have a build.rs that issued its own cargo command, but I couldn't find a flag for cargo that allowed passing a directory to use as root.

There is a command-line argument, but it doesn't expect a directory; rather, it expects a full path to the `Cargo.toml` file. The argument is named `--manifest-path`, and it's available on many subcommands, such as `build` and `run`. It's used like this (note that relative paths are also valid):

```
$ cargo build --manifest-path=/path/to/proj/src/bin/foo-bin-rs/Cargo.toml
```

If you need to run the executable from your build script, you can simply use `cargo run` to build and run in one go, as usual.